# Is it possible to select a count on rows that are similar in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have a very simple table that registers which zipcodes (postcodes) are entered by page visitors. A zipcode always looks like DDDDCC Where D = digit and C = char. I would like to select a count for each row that shows how many zipcodes are similar to that one.

- I know that I need to use `SUBSTRING(postcode, 1, 4)` to get the first 4 digits, but how to proceed from there I don't know

**Table structure** (with sample data)

```
postcode  ip               datum                
--------  ---------------  ---------------------
1651ZX    8X.26.1X4.9X     2017-03-02 22:18:02  
1028HN    84.26.104.9X     2017-03-02 22:19:32  
1871EN    84.26.104.9X     2017-03-02 22:41:47  
1651QQ    84.2X.104.9X     2017-03-02 22:46:35  
1651ZX    188.206.X1.10X   2017-03-02 23:27:07  
1111AB    217.110.X01.13X  2017-03-03 09:12:19  
1871AA    188.206.X0.22X   2017-03-04 21:48:34  
1028HN    188.206.X0.22X   2017-03-04 23:42:19  
1823KA    84.105.X01.1X    2017-03-09 12:28:06  
1871EN    84.105.X01.1X    2017-03-09 12:29:13  
1823JM    84.105.X01.1X    2017-03-09 12:29:40  
1818AJ    84.105.201.14    2017-03-09 12:30:50  
1651ZX    84.105.201.14    2017-03-10 09:17:38
```

My expected output would be (forgive me if I made an error)

```
postcode    count
--------    -------
1651ZX         4
3028HN         2
1871EN         3
1651QQ         4
1651ZX         4
1111AB         1
1871AA         3
3028HN         2
1823KA         2
1871EN         3
1823JM         2
1818AJ         1
1651ZX         4
```

But How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.postcode, t2.post_count
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(postcode, 1, 4) AS code,
           COUNT(*) AS post_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(postcode, 1, 4)
) t2
    ON SUBSTRING(t1.postcode, 1, 4) = t2.code
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much! I learnt a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group by clause

```
SELECT postcode, COUNT(postcode) as `count`
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(postcode, 1, 4)
```